# ASP.NET Core multi-tenant authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, multi-tenant, .net-7.0

With the following authentication configs:

```cs
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtConfigs.Secret);

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultOutboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        // ...
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            // ValidateAudience = ...
            // AudienceValidator = ...
            // ...
        };
    });
```

In a multi-tenant application the problem is that an admin of a tenant can use his/her token to modify other tenants.

So to solve this problem I can think of two solutions:

1. Use a different secret key per tenant
2. Use different audience when issuing the token

For the first one, I could not find any way to specify the secret at runtime (my tenants will be identified based on the host name of the HTTP request, they need to buy a domain).

For the second one, I saw a [AudienceValidator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.audiencevalidator?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest) option, but the delegate does not provide  a HTTP context or a service provider.

If a tenant has the domain `tenant-a.com` then the JWT token of that tenant should work for all of its subdomains.

There is also a `ValidateAudience` boolean property:

```cs
// Remarks:
//     Validation of the audience, mitigates forwarding attacks. For example, a site
//     that receives a token, could not replay it to another side. A forwarded token
//     would contain the audience of the original site. This boolean only applies to
//     default audience validation. If Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters.AudienceValidator
//     is set, it will be called regardless of whether this property is true or false.
//     The default is true.
[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool ValidateAudience { get; set; }
```

It says

> This boolean only applies to default audience validation

I don't know what the default validation is.

Comment: This sounds to me more like an authorization issue. For example, Office 365 uses the same signing keys for pretty much every tenant globally. Sure, using different signing keys adds a layer of security. But a user from another tenant should not be able to edit something in another tenant anyway, even with using the same signing key. You need authorization rules in place to check the user's tenant from their token claims.

Comment: This sounds to me more like an authorization issue +1,I think you may need add a claim (role?) to distiguish admin/other users